# Running a Sqlite batch file to read all .txt files in the same directory

Tags: sqlite, batch-file

Problem is i need to run a batch file that will run all file with .txt extension one at a time, but right now i can only run 1 file manually..

sqlite3 db1.db ".read 1.txt"

saved as a .bat file

what i would like,is for it to read all txt files in the directory because it only works for the above named txt file

Comment: `For %%A In (*.txt) Do <command> "%%A"`, _where `<command>` is your chosen sqlite command and `%%A` is a metavariable containing the name of each returned `.txt` file_. Please open a Command Prompt window, `cmd.exe`, to learn how to use any command, i.e. entering `for /?` will provide the usage information on the `for` command.

Answer (score 0):

Updating answer. Try concatenate your text files, then do the command.

```
copy /b *.txt newfile.txt
sqlite3 db1.db ".read newfile.txt"
```

---You said that may not work because files are too large then, try this as an alternative?

```
:start
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir/b "%~dp0\*.txt"') do (
            set file=%%a
            echo "!file!"
            call :readfile !file!
            )
    ENDLOCAL 

:readfile
sqlite3 db1.db ".read %file%"

pause
:exit
goto :EOF
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't seem to work, the command prompt appears then disappears. when i run the batch file...The sqlite3 file is also in that directory so it should work....but does not ...

Comment: open cmd, drag the bat to it and press enter. Look for errors and report back.

Comment: C:\Users\xxx>C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\SQL\Run.bat

C:\Users\xxx>setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

C:\Users\xxx>for /F "tokens=* delims=" %a in ('dir/b "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\SQL\\*.txt"') do (
set file=%a
 sqlite3 db1.db ""
)

C:\Users\xxx>(
set file=1.txt
 sqlite3 db1.db ""
)
'sqlite3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\xxx>ENDLOCAL

Comment: two things I'd try. First just try putting `START` before sqlite3. If that don't work I would then try SHIFT+RIGHTCLICK on the sqlite3 file and "Copy as Path" then replace the `sqlite3` string in your bat with the full path.

Comment: also it kind of looks like you have `"!file!"` before `sqlite3 db1.db` in your bat based on the output

Comment: my initial bat file worked fine, just had to type in the txt file manually...hmmm

Comment: this should do the same thing. perhaps try ".exe" after sqlite3. "sqlite3 .exe"

Comment: New suggestion, what if you concatenate all those text files first into one file and then you run your command on that one file?

Comment: yh concatenate would definitely work but i dont know how to run it through batch

Comment: type  *.txt > concat.txt
sqlite3.exe db1.db ".read concat.txt"
that works but the txt file it created will be several GB in size, is there another way?

Comment: Give me a few minutes to think on it and I'll maybe try another approach.

Comment: are you open to using powershell?

Comment: powershell in windows 7 or below might a problem, but if there is no other way then yh.

Comment: updated my answer with another batch solution, be sure and run it from a batch file and not from cmd or it wont work.

Comment: Error: unrecognized token: "1.txt"

Comment: it only comes up with error on txt files that have spaces in it, is there anyway around this?

Comment: Under `:readline` I updated this line `sqlite3 db1.db ".read %file%"` I think that should do it.